# Pass array to function, how?

Tags: javascript, json

I have some code that does not quite work as I assumed it would. I am still very much in the learning process, and the code probably looks terrible to some of you. Hopefully you can disregard that and help me out still.

I have constructed a function that turns the columns green once a checkbox is checked, and red when they are not checked. I then push the GREEN values into an array, and return it, when clicking on "add" which looks like this (`<input type="button" id="submit" value="Send data" onclick="sendData(sendMe)">`) I expect it to loop through and alert the values (sendData-function) but nothing happens. If I take the code INSIDE the sendData function and place it in the "ChangeBackGroundColor" it works, but I would like to submit it using XHTMLrequest.

```
function ChangeBackgroundColor(status){
    if (status.checked) {
        status.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "green";
        sendMe = [];
        status.parentNode.previousSibling.style.backgroundColor ="green";
        status.parentNode.previousSibling.previousSibling.style.backgroundColor ="green";
        status.parentNode.previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling.style.backgroundColor ="green";
        sendMe.push(status.parentNode.previousSibling.textContent);
        sendMe.push(status.parentNode.previousSibling.previousSibling.textContent);
        sendMe.push(status.parentNode.previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling.textContent);

                }
    else {
        status.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        status.parentNode.previousSibling.style.backgroundColor ="red";
        status.parentNode.previousSibling.previousSibling.style.backgroundColor ="red";
        status.parentNode.previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling.style.backgroundColor ="red";
        sendMe.pop(status.parentNode.previousSibling.textContent);
        sendMe.pop(status.parentNode.previousSibling.previousSibling.textContent);
        sendMe.pop(status.parentNode.previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling.textContent);


    }
    return sendMe;

}

function sendData(sendMe) {

    var arrayLength = sendMe.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    alert(sendMe[i]);

        }
```

Comment: Have you checked the console for javascript errors? You're using `sendMe` as both a function and an array - one will be erroring.

Comment: I did, thank you. It says that sendMe is undefined, removed the method, and i'm currently returning sendme; but still no go. Problem is that it won't transport the array from the first function into the sendData function, and I can't figure out why

Comment: Why are you settings assignments of the css properties to variables inside the `if`? It looks like the only difference between the two sides of the `if` and `else` is the color. Plus, I don't see how `sendMe` is supposed to be passed as an argument to `sendData`.

Comment: I've removed the var settings in the if statement, I had an idea that got stuck.@krillgar also, please explain in that case how am I supposed to get the array from the first function into the second? That's where I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the ugly way to do what you're attempting to do. Cleaning up your code with closures would result in way too much to explain that is off topic to your question.

```
<input type="button" id="submit" value="Send data" onclick="sendData(sendMe)">

<script>
    // Create your "sendMe" outside of any particular function.
    // This will allow it to be accessed from either function 
    // with the same variable and not have to be passed.
    var sendMe = [];

    function ChangeBackgroundColor(status){
        var color;
        // Reset the array so we don't have the same items on there multiple times.
        sendMe = [];

        if (status.checked) {
            color = "green";
        } else {
            color = "red";
        }

        status.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = color;
        status.parentNode.previousSibling.style.backgroundColor = color;
        status.parentNode.previousSibling.previousSibling.style.backgroundColor = color;
        status.parentNode.previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling.style.backgroundColor = color;
        sendMe.push(status.parentNode.previousSibling.textContent);
        sendMe.push(status.parentNode.previousSibling.previousSibling.textContent);
        sendMe.push(status.parentNode.previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling.textContent);
    }

    function sendData() {
        var arrayLength = sendMe.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
            alert(sendMe[i]);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Appreciate your help! I guess I'm confused. I thought you HAD to pass it between functions in order for it to move from the sort of "global-area" down to functionlevel. Otherwise, why are people doing it? If you can just declare it from anywhere, without it being changed.

Comment: You pass things in as parameters because you only want a specific value to be sent in, as opposed to something that may be a shared variable. The first thing you may encounter this (since it seems like you're new to programming) is event parameters. But if you just have a single set of the data to store between function calls, then there is nothing wrong with storing that in a variable. In a situation like this where they aren't chained or called together, there is not a way to pass it around as a variable.